# python side_effect - mocking behavior of a method

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, side-effects

In the mock, I want a certain function to return a new value in the test. This is how i did it.

```
Class MyClass:

      my_var = None  

      def foo(self, var1):
          return somevalue

      def bar(self):
          my_var = foo(1)

Class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
      myClass = MyClass() 

      def _side_effect_foo(var1):
           if condition:
                return new_value

      @patch("MyClass", "foo", side_effect='_side_effect_foo')
      def test_foo(self):
           self.myClass.bar()
```

This gives me a error:

> Can't pass kwargs to a mock we aren't creating.

Am I using the correct format of side_effect?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. The arguments you're passing to the `@patch` decorator aren't quite right. The target should be specified as a single argument:

   ```
   @patch('MyClass.foo')
   ```
2. Your decorated test function will need to accept an additional argument for the patched target - e.g. `mock_foo`:

   ```
   @patch('MyClass.foo')
   def test_foo(self, mock_foo):
   ```
3. You can then set the side effect on `mock_foo`:

   ```
   @patch('MyClass.foo')
   def test_foo(self, mock_foo):
       mock_foo.side_effect = self._side_effect_foo
   ```
4. In addition, `_side_effect_foo()` should be made a proper instance method with `self` as the first argument:

   ```
   def _side_effect_foo(self, var1):
       if condition:
           return new_value
   ```
5. Lastly, you should instantiate `MyClass` either inside the test method itself, or inside the `setUp()` method:

   ```
   def setUp(self):
       self.myClass = MyClass()

   @patch('MyClass.foo')
   def test_foo(self, mock_foo):
       mock_foo.side_effect = self._side_effect_foo
       self.myClass.bar()
   ```